# Is there a way to have a column in SharePoint which has multiple links?

Tags: 2007, site-column

I currently have a normal SharePoint list with about 15 columns or so. I need one of the columns to have a list of links. I know SharePoint lets you have 1 link and it also lets you have multiple lines of text... So I thought it would be there as an option, but no such luck. Anyone knows a solution for this? I wasn't able to find any info online, which doesn't happen often. I guess I wasn't looking for the right keywords? If anyone can point me into the right direction, it would be great!

Thanks
-V

p.s. I'm reposting this question in this site due to a suggestion from someone in stackoverflow (where I had asked this originally.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multi-line text box can support html/rich text allowing you to include multiple links.  It would essentially be "unstructured" though so if you wanted to use them to support some kind of customization you would need to embed them in xml or something.

Answer (score 0):

You could you create a secondary links list with a lookup to the orignal list.  Then you can use SPD to display all the links as a joined subview.

For example

List 1 - Contains main data but no links.
List 2 - Has a Lookup to the ID's of List 1 and a Link Column.

Add multiple links with the same ID.

Using SharePoint Designer you can use an XSL StyleSheet to link two lists together by creating a linked list and then passing id's across to different templates.  To give a complete user experience you will need to manage how users add links but the basis is there.

Answer (score 0):

A bit like Mike suggested: an option is to used the rich format of the multi line text and define the value directly as string with html content bla, so you can have many of them.

Just had a similar case, adding new items to the list via C# code and CSOM. My links refer to a page on the same sharePoint site. My links seems to work ok, but got shorten by CSOM and contains only a relative link:

[Absolute URLs converted to Relative URLs when saving item](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62887/absolute-urls-converted-to-relative-urls-when-saving-item)

This is a problem for me since I want to send an email with the value of the field, so that user can click on the links from their email. I haven't found a proper solution yet.