# Announcement strips domain name from link

Tags: 2010, list, workflow, email

This is a weird one.

So I post an announcement in an announcements list.  In the message body I create a link that points to a document library and am sure to include the domain name in the link.

There is a workflow attached to the list that will [send the message as an email](https://spdactivities.codeplex.com).  But when it is sent out via email, the domain name is stripped from the link url and so it becomes a broken link!

I went into the message of the announcement afterwards and went to edit the link and, lo and behold! There was no domain name in the url!  Even though I did use one originally.

I tried the same thing in an Announcement list without any workflow attached and found the same issue.

Anyone have a clue why this is happening?  Is there a way to prevent this from happening?  Maybe a setting somewhere?

Does anyone have a solution for this behaviour?

Comment: And if you disable the Publishing Feature?

Comment: Oh, I don't know.  I can't really do that because many things depend on it being enabled.

Comment: I have a vague suspicion the Announcements list is under SharePoints control; just like Links in Pages and the QuickLaunch are changed/managed by SP... but I do not know a solution for you

Comment: SP does this a lot, strip out absolute URLs and makes them relative. I'd say to not insert a hyperlink and just try typing the url normally. Outlook is typically smart enough to turn it into a clickable hyperlink then.

Comment: Yeah, but sharepoin urls are *really* ugly - especially if it leads to a list item or a library item.  But at least, you are right, it is a workaround.

Comment: Also, if you type out the url, it doesn't get hyperlinked in the actual announcement on the portal.

Comment: Is the workflow a 2010 or 2013 workflow? Have you thought about manipulating the content as you put it in the email, rather than when you are saving the list item?

Comment: How do you add a link in the message box? Just type in or from the insert option using either "From SharePoint" or "From Address"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of using a 2013 workflow step to read the Announcment body into a variable called Body, use a "Replace Substring In String" action to replace the text 'href="/' with 'href="http://urltosp/' and then output the updated text to the variable.

You can then send the variable contents in your email.

[image]

Comment: Everything is 2010 (I tagged my question that way, actually) - but this is not a bad idea.  Maybe I can add something like this to my workflow that sends the email.

Comment: This actually works!  I can't believe it!  And for the record, any richtext formatting *IS* retained after the replacement.  This is the solution.  I'll give you the reward, but I have to wait for 10 hours, says the site.

Comment: This has the advantage that the relative links are preserved in the actual announcement item, whilst the absolute url is inserted into the email message.

Comment: Glad that helped!

Comment: PLEASE also note that if you are using single quotes in your href attribute (as Javascript allows you) Sharepoint converts it to double quotes. So do it exactly like @PaulLucas has laid out regardless of if you thought you used single quotes....... Sharepoint... The only development tool I've ever used where the developers are okay with the development tool changing their code :P

Answer (score 0):

This behavior seems to be by design, it's supposed to work with alternate access mappings, but emails are clearly not considered. There's a function in SharePoint Rich Text Editor JavaScript that strips the domain, so if you switch to plain text, your HTML source will not be modified.

See this Q&A as well [Absolute URLs converted to Relative URLs when saving item](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62887/absolute-urls-converted-to-relative-urls-when-saving-item)

*Below is an excerpt from the out-of-the-box SharePoint javascript, for illustration purpose only. Not to be used as a solution.*

```
RTE.RteUtility.$EI = function (a) {
    ULSNVe:
    ;
    var b = new RegExp("[^:]*://" + window.location.hostname + "(:|/)", "i"), c     = new RegExp("[^:]*://", "i");
    return a.search(c) === -1 || a.search(b) !== -1;
};

RTE.RteUtility.$4O = function (e) {
ULSNVe:
    ;
    var a = e, d = window.location.protocol, b = d + "//" +
        window.location.hostname, c = window.location.port;
    if (c === "")
        if (d === "https:")
            c = 443;
        else
            c = 80;
    if (c === 80 && d === "http:" || c === 443 && d === "https:")
        if (a === b)
            return "/";
        else if (!a.indexOf(b + "/"))
            return a.replace(b + "/", "/");
    b += ":" + c;
    if (a === b)
        return "/";
    else if (!a.indexOf(b + "/"))
        return a.replace(b + "/", "/");
    return a;
};
```

Comment: I added this function to the master page, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: In my case this is happening in an announcements list which gets sent to an email distribution list via workflow.  I can't change it to plaintext - it has to be richtext.

Comment: You shouldn't have added this function - it's already there out of the box. I added the code to illustrate what exactly it replaces in the HTML. You could override it, however, as needed.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't tell that you weren't suggesting for me to add it...  It didn't seem to do anything so I removed it.  So, this isn't really a solution, just useful information.

Comment: It's an answer to your question why and whether there is a setting. And a small piece of advice: try to understand the code before you try it live by copying and pasting. Just so you don't do quite the opposite or just break something.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about copy-paste.  I thought what you had posted was an overwrite of the RTE function - I didn't realize you were posting the *original* code.  I understood enough of it to know what I was pasting, although I admit I didn't study it completely.  I might be an idiot, but not completely.

Comment: Please take no offense, it was not intended. Just a cautionary note.

Comment: Okay, I undo my offense-taking.  :)  Thanks for answering.